# When assigning value to class variable in VBA excel, the value is not set. How do I set a class declared variable?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm pretty new to VBA but I have been trying to figure out what is going wrong here. When I try to set a variable declared in my class module from a Sub in my module, the value isn't assigned for some reason and I can't figure out why. How do I get the variable `table` to go all the way through to the function call `response = add_edit_data("fund_management.db", table)`? It all compiles and runs, until it reaches the `add_edit_data` function which of course does not work without this variable. My `Debug.Print checkpopup.table` in the Sub returns nothing although I know the variable `table` from calling the Sub is set correctly as `Debug.Print table` returns the correct value when called from inside the Sub.

My module looks like this:

```
Private checkpopup As class_checkpopup

Public Sub checkbox_popup_fund(table)
    Set checkpopup = New class_checkpopup
    checkpopup.Show
    checkpopup.table = table
    Debug.Print checkpopup.table
End Sub
```

The class module is:

```
Public table As String
Private WithEvents check_box_popup As check_box

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set check_box_popup = New check_box
End Sub

Public Sub Show()
    check_box_popup.Show
End Sub

Private Sub check_box_popup_Closed()
End Sub

Private Sub check_box_popup_Yes()
    response = add_edit_data("fund_management.db", table)
End Sub
```

and I activate the eventhandler with:

```
Public Event Yes()

Private Sub check_box_yes_Click()
    RaiseEvent Yes
End Sub
```

Comment: I might be able to help if I could get your code to compile. which module are you defining the event in? where is check_box defined?

Comment: VBA handles variables in class modules like properties of that class. Therefore you must use `Property Set` (for objects) or `Property Let` procedures to assign a value to it.

Comment: @Nicholas Hunter: check_box is a Form that contains two command buttons and a label. This Event is activated when one of the buttons, the one that says "Yes" is clicked.

@Variatus: I'm not sure what you mean, should the line `checkpopup.table = table` instead be `Let checkpopup.table = table`? I tried that and it didn't work. Still nothing is passed through to my `add_edit_data`

Comment: You need to set the value of table before you show the form. @Variatus is not correct when they say that you "must" use property getters and setters--it's optional--but it is best practice and if you had done so, this issue would have been much easier to diagnose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you to Nicholas Hunter and Variatus for helping me out. I wasn't aware that it mattered to set the variable before showing the Form, but it does. I changed my module to:

```
Private checkpopup As class_checkpopup

Public Sub checkbox_popup_fund(table)
    Set checkpopup = New class_checkpopup
    Let checkpopup.table = table
    checkpopup.Show
    Debug.Print checkpopup.table
End Sub
```

and now my value carries through all the way to my function. Thank you very much for the help